# Get ForeignKey Model dynamically in Django 2

Tags: django, model

Currently I'm trying do determine the Model behind a ForeignKey dynamically. For example I have:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
shift= models.ForeignKey(Workshift, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Workshift(models.Model):
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now I want to do something like Calendar._meta.get_foreign_key_models() (which of cause doesn't exist) and receive the Workshift Model. I already tried the model._meta.get_fields() method, but this only tells me, that shift is a ForeignKey, not which Model stands behind it.
Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The field itself has a property `related_model` so if you fetch the fields, check which ones are instances of `RelatedField` then you can get the `related_model`:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import RelatedField
related_models = [field.related_model for field in Calendar._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(field, RelatedField)]
```

Comment: correct can be `[field.related_model for field in Calendar._meta.get_fields() if getattr(field,'related_model')]`

Comment: `getattr` works also indeed. `hasattr` always returns True, so I changed to check the class.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know the foreignkey field name is shift, get it's related_model by:

```
Calendar._meta.get_field('shift').related_model
```